# Ubuntu 20.10 Server on raspberry pi 4 won't see a network

Tags: networking, server, raspberrypi, 20.10

So I have been trying to set up a WordPress site on Ubuntu 20.10 on a Raspberry Pi 4, and have messed up Configuration files, and other settings on many occasions. So I've flashed my SD card (used as the boot drive) a bunch to get a fresh start when I make a mistake. So I messed up and flashed my SD card using the Raspberry pi Imager tool, I then install Ubuntu 20.10 server, which I've done a bunch. Then I go to set up my network configuration to connect to my network which is named newgateway_5GHz in `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`. Then I proceed to the next steps which are to run `sudo systemctl enable wpa_suppilcant` then `sudo systemctl start wpa_supplicant` and then run `sudo netplan generate` then finally `sudo netplan apply` the I **reboot**. When I reboot the and run `ip a` to check to see if I got an Ip address. I don't get it so I retrace my steps and didn't see anything wrong. Then I used another sd card I had set up as a backup with Raspberry Pi os LITE and updated the firmware and still nothing. So I flash the original sd card again but this time Install Ubuntu 20.10 Desktop for the GUI to see if the newgateway_5GHz is showing. I go to browse available networks to connect too. Interestingly I don't see it listed but I have a windows machine that is connected to the same network. Luckily the router has 2 a second access point called newgateway1. Which I was able to connect to on my Pi. The only difference between newgateway_5GHz and newgateway1 is that newgateway_5GHz is a 5 GHz network, while newgateway1 is only 2.4 GHz. Any ideas on how I could fix my issue?

> **Here is the `etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` configuration I used for newgateway_5GHz**

```
network:
version: 2
ethernets:
    eth0:
        dhcp4: true
        match:
            driver: bcmgenet smsc95xx lan78xx
        optional: true
        set-name: eth0
wifis:
    wlan0:
        access-points:
            "newgateway_5GHz":
                password: "**********"
        optional: true
        dhcp4: true
```

> **Here is the `etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` configuration I used for newgateway1**

```
network:
version: 2
ethernets:
    eth0:
        dhcp4: true
        match:
            driver: bcmgenet smsc95xx lan78xx
        optional: true
        set-name: eth0
wifis:
    wlan0:
        access-points:
            "newgateway1":
                password: "********"
        optional: true
        dhcp4: true
```

> ### Note:
>
> I have replaced the network passwords with * but the character count of the password matches that of the actual passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like you have messed up with spaces. Most of *.yaml files are indentation sensitive. And in your case it should be like next:

```
network:
version: 2
ethernets:
    eth0:
        dhcp4: true
        match:
            driver: bcmgenet smsc95xx lan78xx
        optional: true
        set-name: eth0
wifis:
    wlan0:
        access-points:
            "newgateway1":
                password: "********"
        optional: true
        dhcp4: true
```